# Is there an order you should declare variables in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, variables, declare

I read somewhere that the order you're declaring variables in C++ affects how much space they take.

Is that true? And if yes: What is the order and why is it like this?

Comment: Perhaps, in the same place where you "read somewhere" will also explain, in the same "somewhere", why and how?

Comment: Keyword for further investigation: Padding.

Comment: Not something that needs a lot of worry about unless you have large vectors of items.  If you are really curious, you can print out the address and `sizeof` of each data member, and the `sizeof` of the class instance object, and figure out how much padding or alignment is used for the instance object.

Comment: Yes.  You should declare them alphabetically by name, as close as to the point of usage as possible.  Sorting alphabetically makes the variables easier to find.  Also, declare one variable per line.  This advice can be thrown out the window if you are writing a memory or execution constrained application.

Comment: Don't worry about how much space variables take until you run out of space.  Work on robustness, and quality first.  Other attributes like development time (schedule) may be more important that optimizations, including worrying about how much space variables consume.